# Can some one convert this VB code to VC++

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++

I found this code to move form through panels, but i want this code in c++, as i am null in vb i need help to convert following code in visual c++.

```
'Constants   
Const HTCAPTION = &H2
Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = &HA1

'API functions   
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
Public Shared Function ReleaseCapture() As Boolean
End Function
Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr


'You could Dock a Panel to the top of your form and use:   


Private Sub Panel1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseDown

    'This code can be used in the MouseDown event of any control(s) you want to be able to move your form with   
    ReleaseCapture()
    SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0&)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In your WndProc:

```c
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    ReleaseCapture ();
    SendMessage (hWnd, WM_NCLBUTTONBUTON, HTCAPTION, 0);
    break;
```

Comment: Can you please the above portion of the code please? I know nothing about VB, and spent hours searching but this is most perfect code i found, but its in VB.

Comment: The code I wrote is C, not VB.